# Workday: Put_Customer returning an error

Tags: data-integration, workday-api, snaplogic

We are using Snaplogic to load records into workday. Currently, extracting customer records from the source and trying to load them into workday using the object **Put_Customer** of web service **Revenue_Management**.

I was getting the following error:

[image: Without Customer Category Reference]

But I'm not getting any category information from the source. So, I tried putting the value for Customer_Category_Reference as `1`. But I ended up getting the following error.

[image: With Customer Category Reference value as 1]

The documentation for workday is not helpful and this has been a blocker for me for some time now.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Update:**

Trying to get customer categories using the `Get_Customer_Categories` object of `Revenue_Management` web service using Snaplogic. But getting the following error:

```
Failure: Soap fault, Reason: Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized., Resolution: Address SOAP fault message and retry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have access to a tenant at this time to validate . However it is likely to work based in prior experience .  Perhaps you could create a customer in Workday, through the GUI. Then do get customer API call. Note the category reference . Then, use that in your put customer call

Comment: I don't have access to the tenant. Is there any other way? Otherwise, I'll demand access to the UI?

Comment: You must use an account that has that correct access permissions and security to call the web services. You could either request a service (non-person) account for integration purposes or use your own person account. I would recommend get your own account and use it for the initial development. Then when you put your integrated solution Into production, use an account just for the integration purpose which is not associated with any person's name. Regardless , I believe getting tenant acc as is the only way to use the API .

Comment: Yes, you can use the same account that the web service connects with.

Comment: @cdonner, you can but probably should not in an automated scenario.

Comment: Got access to the UI and now I'm able to post customers using `Put_Customer` and I'm also able to validate through the UI. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @dbh? We were talking about accessing Workday so that he can get the WID for the customer category that he wants to use. That's a one-time task and it is perfectly fine to use a service account for this, imo. Alternatively, you can ask your Workday admin to provide it to you, but that takes longer and he or she may come back with the wrong information. I think @Bilesh may have accepted the wrong answer, though.

Comment: @cdonner, agree accessing to get a WID one time through any account should be fine . I'm WID you on that. I respectfully disagree on your last suggestion. Good to have others with knowledge to share and I'm happy we are both able to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [API documentation](https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/Revenue_Management/v26.2/Put_Customer.html#Customer_CategoryObjectIDType), you will find that Put_Customer accepts a WID in the Customer_WWS_Data object. If you search for "Customer Categories" in Workday, you will likely find the report of the same name. Just select the category that you want your newly loaded customers to default to (click on the magnifying class, then on the ellipsis, Integration Ids, View Ids). The Workday ID will appear at the top.

I have not used the Revenue Management API, but my code for creating a position reference in the Compensation API is probably very similar to what you need to do for the Customer Category reference:

```
public static Position_ElementObjectType getPositionReference(string WID) {

            return new Position_ElementObjectType {
                ID = new Position_ElementObjectIDType[] {
                    new Position_ElementObjectIDType {
                        type = "WID",
                        Value = WID
                    }
                }
            };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for the late reply.
Unfortunately, I don't have access to the tenant UI and when I try to do `Get_Customer_Categories` from snaplogic, I get the error - `Failure: Soap fault, Reason: Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized`.